# Progress Bar lollipop style

Tags: android, progress-bar, android-5.0-lollipop

I need to display a progress like the image displayed below, but without arrow in that.How to do it ? Its not given in design specs but have seen some apps implementing that, is it possible ?

[Design Specs](http://www.google.com/design/spec/components/progress-activity.html#progress-activity-behavior)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For such circular process bar in older SDK level, you can use this custom view   , 
[MaterialLoadingProgressBar](https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/1525)